# Can I be denied a promotion because the job requires car insurance but I don't drive because I have narcolepsy?

Tags: promotion, discrimination, disability

I am thinking of applying for a promotion at work. It requires you to have a certain type of car insurance coverage. However I have narcolepsy and am unable to drive, due to excessive sleepiness making driving unsafe. I was wondering if as long as the person who drives me has that type of insurance required if I could get the promotion or if I would be denied since I am not the one who is driving?

Comment: I guess driving is part of the job you are hoping for? Is the person who is insured going to go to work with you and drive you whenever needed?

Comment: Yes I work at a movie theater and sometimes we have to take deposits to the bank. Yes the person who is insured does work there as well and he can drive me whenever needed since we live together.

Comment: Is it possible for your excessive sleepiness to be treated to the extent that driving won't be unsafe?

Comment: I am on medication for my narcolepsy however I still tend to get sleepy in the car.

Comment: What country are you in? Usually adjustments for disability have to be reasonable, and if the job requires something you cannot do, it may be hard if not impossible to overcome.

Comment: Having a co-worker drive you doubles the cost of the task, You could just have your co-worker do it alone.

Comment: I hate to give you bad news, why would the company pay 2 employees to make the deposit, if they can pay a single person to do the same job? It sounds like you should continue to work with your doctor, to find a medication, that treats your underline condition properly. Your solution to the problem, makes an unreasonable assumption, that individual will always work the same exact shifts as you. You could easily be assigned different shifts depending on the other responsibilities of the position in question.

Comment: Are you sure that this new position you want to apply for only requires car insurance, and not that actually requires a driving license, a working car, and also car insurance?

Answer (score 5):

> I was wondering if as long as the person who drives me has that type of insurance required if I could get the promotion or if I would be denied since I am not the one who is driving?

Have you asked anyone within your company? They would be the ones to make the call on your unique circumstances.

Comment: I plan to talk to my general manager this week to see what she says.

Answer (score -1):

I’d say what you have is a disability. One that would often not get noticed, but that stops you from depositing money with the bank.

In most countries, the company would have to make reasonable allowances for a disability. If one is blind or confined to a wheelchair that might be significant allowances, in your case only a very small amount is needed - like letting someone else to the deposits, or finding someone who drives you to the bank.

I’d say the allowances that were needed are suite reasonable.

Comment: I'm not sure paying 2 people to do a job when one suffices is reasonable accommodation.  Employer could just pay op's coworker and be done.

Comment: I don't think it is a reasonable accommodation to hire someone into a job that requires driving and then have the person say that they can't drive due to a medical condition. People need to be able to perform the core duties of the job. I mean, it isn't discrimination to not hire a blind man to do art appraisal because he is blind.